# Viewing photos when in a different folder to the images

Tags: asp.net, imageurl

The file I am having problems with is my basket.aspx file, which is located in my "passwordProtected" folder. From my basket.aspx file, my images are stored in the ../ folder. How do I get to this folder within ASP.NET when defining a imageurl? e.g.

```
    <asp:Image ID="image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='../<%# Eval("photo") %>'/>
```

because the above does not work..

Comment: Can we see the code-behind, presumably you are getting the image from the database?

Comment: @IrishChieftain yes I'm getting the image from the database. This way works in my products page (in root directory with the images).

Comment: My confusion surrounds the "password protected" bit - is it only signed-in folks that get to see these images? Your question is very vague and lacking the relevant code.

Comment: @irishcheiftain only signed in folks get to see their basket. Otherwise they have to sign in. What other code would be relevant. Do tell.

Comment: Would like to see your DB access layer code (and stored procedure if any). The URL issue is easily fixed. Have you debugged your code to see if the image is actually coming back from the DB?

Comment: @irishchieftain when I move the basket.aspx file to the root folder and delete the '../' from the front of the eval it works

Comment: There's just not enough info in your question. We would need to know the version of ASP.NET and how the membership system is set up. If someone tries to add something to basket without logging in, are they being redirected to the login page, etc. I suggest you start by studying membership - old way of doing it is different from newer Identity for example.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are saying is that the images are located in the directory above the directory containing the `basket.aspx` file.  In a url you generally can't use ../ like you can in the native file system to access the parent directory.  So, the easiest thing to do is to set the `ImageUrl` to the root relative url for the image.

So for example if the `basket.aspx` is located at `/dir1/dir2/basket.aspx` and if the images are located in the directory above that (which is dir1) then setting `ImageUrl='/dir1/<%# Eval("photo") %>'` should work, but as @mason pointed out in the comments setting `ImageUrl='~/dir1/<%# Eval("photo") %>'` is even better since enables your web application to support nesting below other applications.

Comment: `/dir1/<%# Eval("photo")` is not an absolute URL. It's a "root relative URL". And generally within ASP.NET, those should be avoided in favor of "application root relative URL"'s, ex, `~/dir1/<%# Eval("photo")`

Comment: I think if you do a bit of googling you will find that it's much more often referred to as an absolute url than an application root relative url.  :-)  Your point of leading with a ~ is a good one if the poster desires the ability to nest this web application in a sub-folder of another web application.

Comment: No, an absolute URL contains absolutely all parts of the URI and is not relative to anything. An absolute URL would be `https://example.com/images.png`. A schema relative URL would be `//example.com/images.png`, a root relative URL would be `/images.png`, and an application root relative URL (ASP.NET specific) would be `~/images.png`. It is important to get this terminology right so that you do not confuse others and spread misinformation. Please update your answer.

Comment: @mason - with that further explanation I can see that you are correct and you have taught me something, thank you.  I have updated my answer and upvoted your explanation to me.

Comment: It is still better to suggest for ASP.NET to use an application root relative URL. That's the convention, Visual Studio templates use application root relative URL's, and you get compatibility with virtual applications without having to go through the entire site and update the URL's.